# Using images from https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps

I have successfully fetched a location from the place api and collected photo_reference from there which I am now trying to pass on to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/ but when I do I only a failed image in return.

I've also tried manually copying the photo_reference keys from here just to try it out: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=xxx and none of those photo_references seem to work either. I thought my key may be the issue but I have managed to convert one photo_reference and thats when using the one from the documentation that shows a gogle reception disk. What am I doing wrong?

I'm now only putting this url as a src to an  which displays the error image but I can't browse to these images either. I tried using fetch and then I get a Base 64 PNG in return but setting that as src to my image didn't work either (seemed to not be formatted correctly)

The image I'm trying to use is https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=Aap_uEDqrqI3PdqjtllOq5nuQTmo6fR6nKnSQsLbk6rvkOpqQNagMT_E2V_KG-q4WJzjok4ZsqQpHn7Y-DUWjHx2M5mZT_IdfTO6xNTjIE7G4rt94yjHw-v8xuLuV7wyzgSnvPBHUB1zFDO70y2gUyAPeo1J8DdtKcc4DelHPEC10Ah_O14n&key=xxx

How should I display a photo from the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the required `maxheight` and `maxwidth` parameters on your request. For your reference, you can check the documentation on Places Photos: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/photos#place_photo_requests

Here is a working request with the `maxheight` and `maxwidth` parameters (*just put in your own API key*): https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=Aap_uEDqrqI3PdqjtllOq5nuQTmo6fR6nKnSQsLbk6rvkOpqQNagMT_E2V_KG-q4WJzjok4ZsqQpHn7Y-DUWjHx2M5mZT_IdfTO6xNTjIE7G4rt94yjHw-v8xuLuV7wyzgSnvPBHUB1zFDO70y2gUyAPeo1J8DdtKcc4DelHPEC10Ah_O14n&maxheight=600&maxwidth=600&key=xxx